# How to get value of same level element with another elements property

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am not sure if I exactly worded the title correctly - it seems a bit complicated to sum up otherwise though. I will do my best to better explain here.

I have some XML that looks similar to this:

```
<Object type="element">
  <Property name="name1" value="somevalue1"/>
  <Property name="name2" value="somevalue2"/>
  <Property name="name3" value="somevalue3"/>
</Object>
```

I would like to get the `value` of `property name1` with using the `value` of `propery name2`. I have multiple objects that look similar too, but just thought that it would be better to just post one example of it to SO.

I already have the `value` of `property name2` it is just a matter of being able to use it to get what i need. I would also like to do this using XML to LINQ and by using the attributes (going by index could mess things up if the order is changed in the future).

I hope this makes sense. If there are any other questions feel free to comment and I will edit my post to clarify.

Comment: How would you relate the two properties? It is through index or some other attribute? Please elaborate.

Comment: I would like to do it by attribute just as I had said above `I would like to get the value of property name1 with using the value of propery name2` - To exactly answer your question though, I would like to use attributes and avoid using index.

Comment: So you want to iterate through your XML and look for `somevalue2` and then take the value of the element before that?

Comment: @germi - that is correct. I have already done the first part "Iterate through your XML and looke for `somevalue2`. Now I just need the next part.

Comment: Then just iterate through the properties and always look at the value of the next property. If that value is `somevalue2`, take your current property.

Comment: @germi - 1) I am not too sure how to do that and 2) I dont want to do it that way in case the order changes in the future - I would much rather get it by attribute.

Comment: But how could you know the attribute? Is your XML really made up of elements with `name="name1"` and `name="name2"`? Is there any pattern behind the names? If so, please tell us. If not, there is no other way than to hope the order stays the same.

Comment: @germi - I dont want to use indexes, but the way i was thinking it may be able to work in my head is by getting the whole Object container that has value of somevalue2 then selecting the Property object of name1 and then getting the attribute value - i am just unsure how it would be done or if it can be done.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var xml = @"
            <root>
               <Object type=""element"">
                  <Property name=""test1"" value=""testvalue1""/>
                  <Property name=""test2"" value=""testvalue2""/>
                  <Property name=""test3"" value=""testvalue3""/>
               </Object>
               <Object type=""element"">
                  <Property name=""name1"" value=""somevalue1""/>
                  <Property name=""name2"" value=""somevalue2""/>
                  <Property name=""name3"" value=""somevalue3""/>
                </Object>
             </root>";

var att = XDocument.Parse(xml)
            .Descendants("Object")
            .First(ele => ele
                .Elements()
                .Any(child => child.Attribute("value").Value == "somevalue2"))
            .Elements()
            .First(ele => ele.
                Attribute("name").Value == "name1")
            .Attribute("value").Value;
```

Get the `Object` element that has a child with `value="somevalue2"`, then get the `value` base off of `name1`

Comment: I dont want to use indexes, but the way i was thinking it may be able to work in my head is by getting the whole `Object` container that has `value` of `somevalue2` then selecting the `Property` object of `name1` and then getting the attribute `value` - i am just unsure how it would be done. Does that make sense? or am I just going crazy? haha